# How do I "apply" to results of a parameter-less function

Tags: scala

This works:

```
List(3, 1, 2).sorted apply 1
res1: Int = 2
```

And this works:

```
var x = List(3, 1, 2).sorted
x: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
x(1)
res2: Int = 2
```

but this doesn't:

```
List(3, 1, 2).sorted (1)

error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(1)
 required: Ordering[?]
       List(3, 1, 2).sorted (1)
                             ^
```

And even parentheses don't clue the parser in to what I want:

```
(List(3, 1, 2).sorted)(1)

error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(1)
 required: Ordering[?]
       (List(3, 1, 2).sorted)(1)
```

It seems like a natural expression.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `sorted` is not parameterless: it takes an implicit parameter, which you can leave out. That's the problem - your (1) is interpreted as an explicit parameter to `sorted` and not a parameter to the apply method of its return value, as in `List(1, 2, 3).tail(0)`, which works fine. Unfortunately I don't know if there's any solution.

Comment: Have you tried `List(3, 1, 2).sorted()(1)`?

Comment: @Madoc: that doesn't work, you can't leave out the implicit by providing an empty parameter list, the the compiler complains about unspecified parameter.

Comment: List(3, 1, 2).sorted(implicitly[Ordering[Int]])(1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works:

`(Listed(3, 1, 2).sorted _)(1)`,

but I'm not sure whether it is much more convenient to use than:

`Listed(3, 1, 2).sorted apply 1`.

I'd go for the latter anyways.

Comment: Actually, my plan is to assign it to a variable -- it's *readable*, where `apply` is just peculiar.

Answer (score 5):

I think you have to keep the apply. The reason is that sorted **isn't** "parameterless", it's defined as

```
def sorted [B >: A] (implicit ord: Ordering[B]) : List[A]
```

As this is an implicit parameter, the Ordering[Int] is normally provided automatically, but if you use parens, the compiler thinks you want to specify another Ordering[Int] (let's say backwards).

Comment: So you're saying I'm screwed?  Why didn't wrapping it in parens help?

Comment: Because parens don't change anything here. Consider `(math.abs)(-1)`: The first parens don't prevent abs from receiving its argument. The same is true for `sorted`, so it just expects an arg for its argument list with the implicit. Nice workaround from Saew, BTW.

Answer (score 3):

The required parameter can be provided this way:

```
List(3, 1, 2).sorted(implicitly[Ordering[Int]])(1)
```

Though using apply() looks shorter and less scary.

Answer (score 2):

The shortest you could make it--not without a small performance penalty, however--is

```
class Allow_\[A](a: A) { def \ = a }
implicit def allowEveryone[A](a: A) = new Allow_\[A](a)

scala> List(1,3,2).sorted\(1)
res0: Int = 2
```

If you can accept another character, this might be nicer: `<>` looks like parens anyway, and can be read as "please fill in the implicit parameters like usual":

```
class Allow_<>[A](a: A) { def <> = a }
implicit def allowEveryone[A](a: A) = new Allow_<>[A](a)

scala> List(1,3,2).sorted<>(1)
res0: Int = 2
```